# Why does this LOOKUP function work like this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

Can you please help me understand why this LOOKUP function works as it does? The formula in yellow-highlighted cell A6 seems to return the label (from row 2) above the rightmost non-zero data value (from row 3).

Image of Microsoft Excel spreadsheet excerpt

[image]

The formula is `=LOOKUP(1000,1/(A3:G3<>0),A2:G2)`

I'm puzzled by:

- The data cells are not sorted (the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) says they ought to be)
- The lookup vector is "1/(A3:G3<>0)". I guess we're generating a vector by dividing the data values into 1, but what is the effect of "<>0"?
- The lookup value is 1000, but the results are the same with other values.

Is there a more direct, more reliable or less confusing way of achieving the same thing? ie, returning the label above the rightmost non-zero data value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should re-read the documentation in the link you provided, which states that:

"*The values in **lookup_vector** must be placed in ascending order*"

and here that array is not simply the values in `A3:G3`, since they are being manipulated into the expression

`1/(A3:G3<>0)`

which *will* form an array in ascending order, the reason being that - and using the data set provided - it will resolve to:

`1/({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE})`

which is:

`{1,#DIV/0!,1,1,1,1,#DIV/0!}`

i.e. an array which can only ever comprise unity or a #DIV/0! error. And since `LOOKUP` ignores error values, this array can indeed be said to be in ascending order.

Using 1000 as the *lookup_value* is fine though a touch overkill: any number larger than 1 will suffice.

Comment: Thankyou Jos for that clear explanation. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As an O365 Excel customer you should have access to other functions that will do exactly what you want to do, by using the newer XLOOKUP function instead of LOOKUP.

Use: `=XLOOKUP(TRUE,A3:G3>0,A2:G2,,0,-1)`

The `A3:G3>0` creates a dynamic array which for your particular example is: `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}`

Further, the `-1` argument at the end of the XLOOKUP() says "search from last".
This XLOOKUP says "Find the first time A3:G3>0 is TRUE, *starting from the right* and return the value of the corresponding cell in row 2."

Also, THANK YOU for putting your Excel version's "about" string in your question.  That is unbelievably useful information.

Comment: Max, thank you for that idea. It seems more direct than the method in the question.